# Second line indent alignment with custom sprite

Tags: html, css

I've made a custom icon for lists using li:before.

```
li:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 13px;
    background: url(../img/sprites.png) no-repeat -85px -336px;
    content: " ";
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

The problem is when the list item breaks into two lines, the second line goes underneath the sprite.
How can I make the indent of the second to align with the text above it?

Thanks!

Comment: It's esier not to use sprites here, but a a simple image and either setting the `list-style-image` or a `background-image` directly on the `li` with padding.

Answer (score 0):

Found out that absolute positioning for the li plus a bit of margin tweaking was in the end the best option.